# Load Balancing in fog computing

Tags: cloud, load-balancing, fog

I have been trying to use fog sim to try and compare different load balancing algorithms and to check for efficiency, power, and distribution of tasks but i am not able to find java code for load balancing algorithms nor good material which can explain how i can use fog sim. Since i have no previous experience in java it is proving to be much harder. Please suggest which tool would be better to use to simulate load balancing in fog and also where i can find the suitable code for these algorithms ???

Comment: Hi, me and my team are trying to code load balancing algorithms in ifogsim as well. Did you make any progress with your tasks?